# Ray Tune| RuntimeError: No best trial found for the given metric: mean_accuracy. This means that no trial has reported this

Tags: ray

`Error: RuntimeError: No best trial found for the given metric: mean_accuracy. This means that no trial has reported this metric, or all values reported for this metric are NaN. To not ignore NaN values, you can set the` filter_nan_and_inf `arg to False.`

Here is my code:

```
`import argparse
import os

from filelock import FileLock
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
import tensorflow as tf
#import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')
import pennylane as qml
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import ray
from ray import train, tune
from ray.tune.schedulers import AsyncHyperBandScheduler
from ray.air.integrations.keras import ReportCheckpointCallback

mnist = keras.datasets.mnist

# datasets are numpy.ndarrays
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()     

# normalize the image data
X_train, X_test = X_train / 255.0, X_test / 255.0

def one_hot(labels):  
       
    depth =  2**4                       # 10 classes + 6 zeros for padding
    indices = labels.astype(np.int32)    
    one_hot_labels = np.eye(depth)[indices].astype(np.float32) 
    
    return one_hot_labels

# one-hot encoded labels, each label of length cutoff dimension**2
y_train, y_test = one_hot(Y_train), one_hot(Y_test)

# using only 600 samples for training in this experiment
n_samples = 600
test_samples = 100
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X_train[:n_samples], X_test[:test_samples], y_train[:n_samples], y_test[:test_samples]

def encode_data(x):
    qml.Squeezing(x[0], x[1], wires=0)
    qml.Squeezing(x[2], x[3], wires=1)
    qml.Squeezing(x[4], x[5], wires=2)
    qml.Squeezing(x[6], x[7], wires=3)
    
    qml.Beamsplitter(x[8], x[9], wires=[0,1])
    qml.Beamsplitter(x[10], x[11], wires=[1,2])
    qml.Beamsplitter(x[12], x[13], wires=[2,3])
    
    qml.Rotation(x[14], wires=0)
    qml.Rotation(x[15], wires=1)
    qml.Rotation(x[16], wires=2)
    qml.Rotation(x[17], wires=3)    
    
    qml.Displacement(x[18], x[19], wires=0)
    qml.Displacement(x[20], x[21], wires=1)
    qml.Displacement(x[22], x[23], wires=2)
    qml.Displacement(x[24], x[25], wires=3) 
    
    qml.Kerr(x[26], wires=0)
    qml.Kerr(x[27], wires=1)
    qml.Kerr(x[28], wires=2)
    qml.Kerr(x[29], wires=3)

def layer(v):
    
    # Linear transformation W = Interferemeter, squeezers, interferometer
    # Interferometer 1
    qml.Beamsplitter(v[0], v[1], wires=[0,1])
    qml.Beamsplitter(v[2], v[3], wires=[1,2])
    qml.Beamsplitter(v[4], v[5], wires=[2,3])
    
    qml.Rotation(v[6], wires=0)
    qml.Rotation(v[7], wires=1)
    qml.Rotation(v[8], wires=2)
    qml.Rotation(v[9], wires=3)
    
    # Squeezers
    qml.Squeezing(v[10], 0.0, wires=0)
    qml.Squeezing(v[11], 0.0, wires=1)
    qml.Squeezing(v[12], 0.0, wires=2)
    qml.Squeezing(v[13], 0.0, wires=3) 
    
    # Interferometer 2
    qml.Beamsplitter(v[14], v[15], wires=[0,1])
    qml.Beamsplitter(v[16], v[17], wires=[1,2])
    qml.Beamsplitter(v[18], v[19], wires=[2,3])
    
    qml.Rotation(v[20], wires=0)
    qml.Rotation(v[21], wires=1)
    qml.Rotation(v[22], wires=2)
    qml.Rotation(v[23], wires=3)
    
    # Bias addition
    qml.Displacement(v[24], 0.0, wires=0)
    qml.Displacement(v[25], 0.0, wires=1)
    qml.Displacement(v[26], 0.0, wires=2)
    qml.Displacement(v[27], 0.0, wires=3)
    
    # Non-linear activation
    qml.Kerr(v[28], wires=0)
    qml.Kerr(v[29], wires=1)
    qml.Kerr(v[30], wires=2)
    qml.Kerr(v[31], wires=3)

def init_weights(layers, modes, active_sd=0.0001, passive_sd=0.1):
    
    # Number of interferometer parameters: beamsplitter + 2 rotations
    M = 10 

    int1_weights = tf.random.normal(shape=[layers, M], stddev=passive_sd)
    s_weights = tf.random.normal(shape=[layers, modes], stddev=active_sd)
    int2_weights = tf.random.normal(shape=[layers, M], stddev=passive_sd)
    dr_weights = tf.random.normal(shape=[layers, modes], stddev=active_sd)
    k_weights = tf.random.normal(shape=[layers, modes], stddev=active_sd)

    weights = tf.concat([int1_weights, s_weights, int2_weights, dr_weights, k_weights], axis=1)
    weights = tf.Variable(weights)

    return weights

num_modes = 4
cutoff_dim = 2

# select a devide 
dev = qml.device("strawberryfields.fock", wires=num_modes, cutoff_dim=cutoff_dim) 

@qml.qnode(dev, interface="tf")
def quantum_nn(inputs, var):
    # Encode input x into quantum state
    encode_data(inputs)

    # iterative quantum layers
    for v in var:
        layer(v)

    return qml.probs(wires=[0, 1, 2, 3])  # Measurement



weight_shape = {'var': (4,32)}          # 4 layers and 32 parameters per layer, Keras layer will initialize.

num_layers = 4

weights = init_weights(num_layers, num_modes)

# convert the quantum layer to a Keras layer
shape_tup = weights.shape
weight_shapes = {'var': shape_tup}
print(weight_shapes)

def train_mnist(config):

    batch_size = 128
    num_classes = 10
    epochs = 12

    '''
        with FileLock(os.path.expanduser("~/.data.lock")):
        (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
    '''

    model = keras.models.Sequential([
                                 layers.Flatten(input_shape = (28,28)),
                                 layers.Dense(392, activation ="elu"),
                                 layers.Dense(196, activation ="elu"),
                                 layers.Dense(98),
                                 layers.Dense(49, activation ="elu"),
                                 layers.Dense(30),
                                ])
    '''
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
        [
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(config["hidden"], activation="relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"),
        ]
    )
    '''
    qlayer = qml.qnn.KerasLayer(quantum_nn, weight_shapes, output_dim = 4)
    model.add(qlayer)
    opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate = 0.02)
    model.compile(opt, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics =['accuracy'])
    '''
        model.compile(
        loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=config["lr"], momentum=config["momentum"]),
        metrics=["accuracy"],
    )
    
    '''
    model.fit(X_train, 
                   y_train,
                   epochs = 200,
                   batch_size = 64,
                   shuffle = True, 
                   validation_data = (X_test, y_test))
    '''
       model.fit(
        x_train,
        y_train,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        verbose=0,
        validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
        callbacks=[ReportCheckpointCallback(metrics={"mean_accuracy": "accuracy"})],
    )
    '''


 def tune_mnist():
    sched = AsyncHyperBandScheduler(
        time_attr="training_iteration", max_t=400, grace_period=20
    )

    tuner = tune.Tuner(
        tune.with_resources(train_mnist, resources={"cpu": 2, "gpu": 0}),
        tune_config=tune.TuneConfig(
            metric="mean_accuracy",
            mode="max",
            scheduler=sched,
            num_samples=10,
        ),
        run_config=train.RunConfig(
            name="exp",
            stop={"mean_accuracy": 0.99},
        ),
        param_space={
            "threads": 2,
            "lr": tune.uniform(0.001, 0.1),
            "momentum": tune.uniform(0.1, 0.9),
            "hidden": tune.randint(32, 512),
        },
    )
    results = tuner.fit()

    print("Best hyperparameters found were: ", results.get_best_result().config)

tune_mnist()`
```

track of error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 29
     25     results = tuner.fit()
     27     print("Best hyperparameters found were: ", results.get_best_result().config)
---> 29 tune_mnist()

Cell In[7], line 27, in tune_mnist()
      6 tuner = tune.Tuner(
      7     tune.with_resources(train_mnist, resources={"cpu": 2, "gpu": 0}),
      8     tune_config=tune.TuneConfig(
   (...)
     23     },
     24 )
     25 results = tuner.fit()
---> 27 print("Best hyperparameters found were: ", results.get_best_result().config)

File /opt/conda/envs/tf1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ray/tune/result_grid.py:162, in ResultGrid.get_best_result(self, metric, mode, scope, filter_nan_and_inf)
    151     error_msg = (
    152         "No best trial found for the given metric: "
    153         f"{metric or self._experiment_analysis.default_metric}. "
    154         "This means that no trial has reported this metric"
    155     )
    156     error_msg += (
    157         ", or all values reported for this metric are NaN. To not ignore NaN "
    158         "values, you can set the `filter_nan_and_inf` arg to False."
    159         if filter_nan_and_inf
    160         else "."
    161     )
--> 162     raise RuntimeError(error_msg)
    164 return self._trial_to_result(best_trial)

RuntimeError: No best trial found for the given metric: mean_accuracy. This means that no trial has reported this metric, or all values reported for this metric are NaN. To not ignore NaN values, you can set the `filter_nan_and_inf` arg to False.
```

I tried to set "filter_nan_and_inf=False", but failed!